# ActiveRecord Error Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone point me the error in this statement?

```
2011-08-19T20:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
2011-08-19T20:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "app_permissions".* FROM "app_permissions" WHERE (user_id = 1,2 AND is_shared = 't' AND app_id = '1')):
2011-08-19T20:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Code:

```
AppPermission.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND is_shared = ? AND app_id = ?", User.find_all_by_facebook_id(@friends_uids).collect { |itm| itm["id"] }, true, @appl_id])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is in the first/second `AND` condition. You may want to change this to:

```
AppPermission.find(:all,
  :conditions => ["user_id in (?) AND is_shared = ? AND app_id = ?",
              User.find_all_by_facebook_id(@friends_uids).collect { |itm| itm["id"] }, 
              true, @appl_id])
```

**EDIT:** you need `IN (?)` because you are getting a collection, not only one value, take a look at the final query in your log and you'll see it (`1,2`)

Comment: Why do I need `in (?)` because it might be a collection as a result of `User.find_all_by_facebook_id(@friends_uids).collect { |itm| itm["id"] }` ? If this statement returned only one `User` my code was working

Comment: Updated! It is related with your `find_all` method retrieving more than one value.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing:

```
user_id = ?
```

to

```
user_id IN (?)
```

Presumably, it hasn't gotten to the error with the comma yet, and it's looking at "2 AND is_shared = 't'".